# How to get the idToken for a user without the user's password? AWS-Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito for the user management.  I want to achieve a feature called "login as".  Basically, the admin can use this feature to login as a specific user.  The APIs I designed require idTokens for the authentication.  So if I am able to get the idToken of a user, then I am able to login as the user.

Therefore, the question is "is there a way or Cognito API to get the idToken of a specific user without user's password?".

Comment: Do you mean without the user's authorization? ID Tokens need to be requested at authorization and the user must grant that. Also, note that ID Tokens expire.

Comment: @John Hanley, yes, without the user's password.

Comment: Not possible. Identity Tokens contain privileged information and represent the "identity" of the user. For some systems, access is granted with Identity Tokens.

Comment: @John Hanley, got, thanks~

Answer (score 4):

No this isn't possible and there is a very good reason for it. It ensures that the admin cannot simply log in as user and make changes under his name. Only the user is allowed to use his account. If that wasn't the case you would not have data [integrity](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Confidentiality-integrity-and-availability-CIA) or [non-repudiation](https://www.cryptomathic.com/products/authentication-signing/digital-signatures-faqs/what-is-non-repudiation)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Can you think of other ways to achieve what I want?

Comment: The exception is authorized "impersonation". However, your answer is correct based upon the question asked.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by logging in as user? If you simply want access to their resources you can create another group with more privileges who can do this.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you, that is good to know. I knew it was something that was wrong but couldn't find the exact term.